# CAML Query string beings with any number

Tags: sharepoint, sharepoint-2010, sharepoint-2007, caml

Is there an easy way to return all strings that begin with a number in a CAML query?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Is this a one-time query or do you want to implement it somehow?

If onetime, then you can use this query:

```
  <Where>
      <Or>
         <Or>
            <Or>
               <Or>
                  <Or>
                     <Or>
                        <Or>
                           <Or>
                              <Or>
                                 <BeginsWith>
                                    <FieldRef Name='Title' />
                                    <Value Type='Text'>0</Value>
                                 </BeginsWith>
                                 <BeginsWith>
                                    <FieldRef Name='Title' />
                                    <Value Type='Text'>1</Value>
                                 </BeginsWith>
                              </Or>
                              <BeginsWith>
                                 <FieldRef Name='Title' />
                                 <Value Type='Text'>2</Value>
                              </BeginsWith>
                           </Or>
                           <BeginsWith>
                              <FieldRef Name='Title' />
                              <Value Type='Text'>3</Value>
                           </BeginsWith>
                        </Or>
                        <BeginsWith>
                           <FieldRef Name='Title' />
                           <Value Type='Text'>4</Value>
                        </BeginsWith>
                     </Or>
                     <BeginsWith>
                        <FieldRef Name='Title' />
                        <Value Type='Text'>5</Value>
                     </BeginsWith>
                  </Or>
                  <BeginsWith>
                     <FieldRef Name='Title' />
                     <Value Type='Text'>6</Value>
                  </BeginsWith>
               </Or>
               <BeginsWith>
                  <FieldRef Name='Title' />
                  <Value Type='Text'>7</Value>
               </BeginsWith>
            </Or>
            <BeginsWith>
               <FieldRef Name='Title' />
               <Value Type='Text'>8</Value>
            </BeginsWith>
         </Or>
         <BeginsWith>
            <FieldRef Name='Title' />
            <Value Type='Text'>9</Value>
         </BeginsWith>
      </Or>
   </Where>
```

Another way is to fetch all items, use SPListItemCollection.[GetDataTable()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.sharepoint.splistitemcollection.getdatatable.aspx) method to return datatable, and filter your records there.

If List will contain many items, this way is not recommended, as it involves getting all items from list.

If, however, you want to implement this in somekind of feature, maybe it would be better to have another column that indicates type of record.

If you go with using this query in a feature, create an index for that column.

Comment: you can use LINQ to build CAML query....no worry about closing tags http://sharepointdeveloper.de/21.html

Comment: Can you check a parameters value equals a string in CAML?

Comment: @Burt, you mean query string parameters? Why not. Just construct your caml query like "<Value type='text'>"+queryStringValue+"</Value>" or better yet use camlex as mentioned above if you don't want or need to know CAML.

Comment: I hate CAML. This is ridiculous. <or><or><or><or><or><or><or><or><or><or><or><or><or><or><or><or><or><or>

Comment: @iambriansreed luckily, starting from SharePoint 2010, you can use LINQ to query SharePoint: http://msdn.microsoft.com/library/ee535491